# Python argparse argument that is python keyword

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I want to have a python command line argument `--lambda`, but I can't access it as lambda is a python keyword.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--lambda')
args = p.parse_args()

print args.lambda
```

I get:

```
print args.lambda
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a different name for the attribute with `dest` e.g.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--lambda', dest='llambda')
args = p.parse_args()

print args.llambda
```

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` uses `hasattr` and `getattr` to set values in the Namespace.  This allows you to use flags/dest that are not valid in the `args.dest` syntax.  Here the problem is with a restricted key word.  It could also be a string with special characters.   So `getattr(args, 'lambda')` should work.

`vars(args)` creates a dictionary, allowing you to use `vars(args)['lambda']`.

But changing the dest is a cleaner solution.  That's part of why that parameter is allowed.

(For a positional argument, choose a valid dest right away.)